# Is it possible to add custom modifier to jest expect assertion?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

As you may know it is possible to add modifier to expect assertions like `.not`, or `.resolves`.

I was wondering if it's possible to add custom expect modifier, I cannot find any resource on that subject.

My use case is that I make assertion on a stringified http response. To ease my testing workflow, I have made some custom matchers for a few assertions:

```js
  toHaveJsonBodyIncludingSameMembers(members: any[]): R;
  toHaveJsonBodyIncludingAllMembers(members: any[]): R;
  toHaveJsonBodyIncludingAllPartialMembers(members: any[]): R;
  toHaveJsonBodyIncludingAnyMembers(members: any): R;
  toHaveJsonBodySatisfying<E = any>(predicate: (actual: E) => boolean): R;
```

It's kind of cumbersome to implement, and for all these matchers I always implement it the same way:

- I parse the JSON body
- then I call an existing matcher from jest-extended

If I could make a custom modifier, instead of writing:

```js
expect(someStringResponse).toHaveJsonBodyIncludingSameMembers(['a', 'b'])
```

I could write:

```js
expect(someStringResponse).jsonBody.toIncludeSameMembers(['a', 'b']);
```

The main benefit would be that I would not need to implement all the matchers but only one modifier, whom responsability would be to unwrap the JSON body, ie. parsing it.
With this modifier, all the existing matchers would be accessible on the unwrapped value.

Any clue on how to do that ? Or if it is even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It isn't easily possible using the library as it currently stands.

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/2499cf2a3a75824fd0c9b454baa95fc75929f086/packages/expect/src/index.ts#L116C1-L116C1), I found the following in the `expect` method:

```
Object.keys(allMatchers).forEach(name => {
    const matcher = allMatchers[name];
    const promiseMatcher = getPromiseMatcher(name, matcher) || matcher;
    expectation[name] = makeThrowingMatcher(matcher, false, '', actual);
    expectation.not[name] = makeThrowingMatcher(matcher, true, '', actual);

    expectation.resolves[name] = makeResolveMatcher(
      name,
      promiseMatcher,
      false,
      actual,
      err,
    );
    expectation.resolves.not[name] = makeResolveMatcher(
      name,
      promiseMatcher,
      true,
      actual,
      err,
    );

    expectation.rejects[name] = makeRejectMatcher(
      name,
      promiseMatcher,
      false,
      actual,
      err,
    );
    expectation.rejects.not[name] = makeRejectMatcher(
      name,
      promiseMatcher,
      true,
      actual,
      err,
    );
  });
```

It looks like each of the modifiers available in jest is actually just a property on the resulting expectation object. Each is its own expectation with whatever properties set to express the intent of the modifier (e.g., the `.not` modifier sets the property to show that it has been negated). All of the matchers need to be copied onto all of these objects.

The only way to add your own modifier would be to write code similar to this. You would need to loop through all of the matchers and supply your own property on the expectation. There currently isn't a good way to do this for all expectations in the app, since the only real built-in way to modify all the expectations that will be created while testing an app is to use the [extend method](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers), but that only accepts new matchers.

As I see it, there are two methods that could solve your problem. One you listed in the question, which is to create your own matchers. This isn't ideal since you would need to create new versions of all the matchers you would like to use when unwrapping your json object.

Another approach would be to move the unwrapping logic earlier in the line. I am proposing that you would probably wrap the `expect` function instead, something along the lines of:

```js
export function expectJson(json: MyCustomJsonType) {
    // Add JSON unwrapping logic here

    return expect(jsonResult);
}
```

This allows you to have an easy way to include your custom unwrapping logic, while at the same time being able to use all the built-in modifiers/matchers etc.

You also could just create a function to call inside the expect call, such as:

```js
expect(extractJson(result))
```

Comment: thansk for your answer.

I love your idea of extending the expect, I will give it a try